# override Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save.php file

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, admin-controller

How to override

> Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save.php

the file can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/code/StackExchange/ControllerOverride/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "stackexchange/controlleroverride",
    "description": "StackExchange ControllerOverride",
    "require": {
      "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6",
      "magento/module-store": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-theme": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-widget": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-backend": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-catalog": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-email": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-ui": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-variable": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-media-storage": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/framework": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.74.0-beta4",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "StackExchange/ControllerOverride"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**app/code/StackExchange/ControllerOverride/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_ControllerOverride',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/StackExchange/ControllerOverride/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save" type="StackExchange\ControllerOverride\Controller\Magento\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save" />

</config>
```

**app/code/StackExchange/ControllerOverride/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_ControllerOverride" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/StackExchange/ControllerOverride/Controller/Magento/Sales/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Save.php**

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\ControllerOverride\Controller\Magento\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Create;


class Save extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save
{


}
```

**EDIT**

If you want order ID after place order, you can use observer as per below tutorial.

https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-order-data-from-magento-2-sales_order_place_after-event/

Comment: thanks for quick replay and i will check now , let u know.

Comment: i am checking and after that i will surely accept it give me 10 mins time  to check.

Comment: Hi @kishan i have overrided but giving below error when i am trying to place an order from admin

Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '187185177-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_order` (`state`, `status`

Comment: I have overrided but giving below error when i am trying to place an order from admin throwing saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '187185177-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_order` (`state`, `status`

Comment: Your answer is not working kindly check your side please

Comment: It's not related to my code. What you wrote in your controller ?

Comment: i have added the whole execute function code from Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save.php

Comment: i want order id to print in custom logs that's the reason

Comment: It is not proper way to override. Only override method that you need to customize.

Comment: can u pls help me out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85370/discussion-between-kishan-patadia-and-gajjala-sandeep).

Comment: it's my bad and now your solution is working.